# Secure a Nodejs console app with client flow and IdentityServer4

Tags: identityserver4

I have a nodejs console client app that call an api from my api server.
I would like to secure the api so that only cal call from my client app.
can anybody give me scaffolding sample with `IdentityServer4`?

Comment: Have you tried the [Identity server docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/4_javascript_client.html) on the subject?

Comment: Yes. The sample not have any console client in nodejs.

Comment: I see. But I think your 'console app' is still just JS running in NodeJS. The console app is the 'client' and the API is the resource that Idsr protects. Or am I wrong? As to whether there are examples ready made.. maybe. If you search for them on Google you'll probably find something similar that you can use.